# Add multiple rows from same model AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js

Considering I have a list of users to add into my system and I don't want to do it one-by-one process. Then I want to see one user form (name, email, password fields) and by the end of the row i see the "add another row" button.

By clicking on "add another row" button, one more user form would be add after the existing one.

How can I send multiple users through only one POST request in AngularJS?

Comment: You can submit pretty much anything as part of a POST request, including a list of users. Is there a specific part of this that is not working for you?

Comment: Christina, I dont have any code for it yet. Trying to understand how I can do it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have an array of users in your controller and every time you press "Add another user" you can add a new user to your array.

The code in your controller:

```
    $scope.users = [{ name: "1" , email: "email1", password:"pas1" }, { name: "2" , email: "email2", password:"pas2"}];;

$scope.addUser = function () {

    $scope.users.push({ name: "" , email: "", password:""  });
};
```

Now, in your html will be a list with the users binding in your array. Adding a new user every time adds a new line in html with views binding on the parameters of the new user added.

```
 <form ng-submit="submit()">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <li class="list-group-item col-xs-12" data-ng-repeat="user in users">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" ng-model="user.name">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.password">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" ng-model="user.email">
            </li>
            <button class="col-xs-12" ng-click="addUser()">Add Another User</button>

    </div>


</form>
```

Add a function submit also to your controller to submit with the way you want your user array. Hopes it helps.

Comment: In the past, when I worked with php we had to set input name to something like 'users[]' to get an array on the request. And now the angular controller will handle it, summarizing. Cool! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is some pretty basic Angular stuff. Here is an example:

```
<form name="usersForm" ng-submit="save()">
    <div ng-repeat="user in users">
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" required />
        <br/>
        <label>Email:</label>
        <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" required />
        <hr/>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="newUser($event)">Add another one</button>

    <input type="submit" value="Save" ng-disabled="usersForm.$invalid || !users.length" />
</form>
```

And a controller to handle the data:

```
$scope.users = [];

$scope.newUser = function($event){
    // prevent submission
    $event.preventDefault();
    $scope.users.push({});
}

$scope.save = function(){
    console.log($scope.users);  
    // myService.saveUsers($scope.users);
    // $http.post("someUrlWhichHandlesListOfUsers", { users: $scope.users });
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tthj5Le9/)

Answer (score 0):

You can post anything you want with `$http.post()`. Is something not working?
Given, your users are stored in $scope.users, in your "save" method you can just write:

```
$http.post('/someUrl', $scope.users).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log('POSTed!');
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log('Failed!');
  });
```

And your JSON object will be sent to the server.